# Copy the most recent of two files with Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a Windows directory which contains 4 files in total. The file names are as follows:

- Address_1502.csv
- Address_1602.csv
- Site_1502.csv
- Site_1602.csv

The prefix of the file name never changes so the files will always begin with `Address_` or `site_`. I am trying to find a command which can copy the most recent of the two files from their current directory in to a different directory. I currently have the following script however this only finds the newest of all 4 files and copies it over however I would like to find the newest of the two Address_ files AND the newest of the two Site_ files.

Can anyone help at all?

```
set "source=D:\TEMP_ONLY\SOURCE"
set "dest=D:\TEMP_ONLY\DESTINATION"
pushd "%source%" ||(
   echo.Source does not exist&pause&goto EOF)

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
   'dir /A-D /OD /B') Do set "file=%%f"
popd
xcopy /d /i "%source%\%file%" "%dest%\"
```

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539726/how-to-get-the-most-recent-file-using-a-batch-script-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

#### I would like to find the newest of the two Address_ files AND the newest of the two Site_ files.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "source=D:\TEMP_ONLY\SOURCE"
set "dest=D:\TEMP_ONLY\DESTINATION"
pushd "%source%" || ( echo.Source does not exist & pause & goto done2)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir Address_*.csv /a-d /b /O:d') do (
  xcopy /d /i "%source%\%%a" "%dest%\"
  goto :done1
  )
:done1   
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir Site_*.csv /a-d /b /O:d') do (
  xcopy /d /i "%source%\%%a" "%dest%\"
  goto :done2
  )
:done2
popd
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.